# AJAX, HTML5 Image previewer + removal before upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I got an image preview working and uploading. My question is how can I make the code only upload whatever is in the preview area? ie. if I select images and remove them, they should not get uploaded upon submission.

I got it to work with jquery with a fake "upload" just to illustrate what I am after but not sure how to send only the images in the preview area to PHP.

If I can somehow get this dynamic list of the images from the preview area into an array, I will easily be able to upload them with PHP, the hard part is getting that list!

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WCCM7/3/

```
var $fileUpload = $("#files"),
    $list = $('#list'),
    thumbsArray = [],
    maxUpload = 5;

// READ FILE + CREATE IMAGE
function read( f ) {
  return function( e ) {
    var base64 =  e.target.result;
    var $img = $('<img/>', {
      src: base64,
      title: encodeURIComponent(f.name), //( escape() is deprecated! )
      "class": "thumb"
    });
    var $thumbParent = $("<span/>",{html:$img, "class":"thumbParent"}).append('<span class="remove_thumb"/>');
    thumbsArray.push(base64); // Push base64 image into array or whatever.
    $list.append(  $thumbParent  );
  };
}

// HANDLE FILE/S UPLOAD
function handleFileSelect( e ) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Needed?
    var files = e.target.files;
    var len = files.length;
    if(len>maxUpload || thumbsArray.length >= maxUpload){
      return alert("Sorry you can upload only 5 images");
    }
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) { 
        var f = files[i];
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) continue; // Only images allowed      
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = read(f); // Call read() function
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
} 

$fileUpload.change(function( e ) {
    handleFileSelect(e);
});

$list.on('click', '.remove_thumb', function () {
    var $removeBtns = $('.remove_thumb'); // Get all of them in collection
    var idx = $removeBtns.index(this );   // Exact Index-from-collection
    $(this).closest('span.thumbParent').remove(); // Remove tumbnail parent
    thumbsArray.splice(idx, 1); // Remove from array
}); 


// that's it. //////////////////////////////
// Let's test //////////////////////////////

$('#upload').click(function(){
  var testImages = "";
  for(var i=0; i<thumbsArray.length; i++){
    testImages += "<img src='"+thumbsArray[i]+"'>";
  }
  $('#server').empty().append(testImages);
});
```

What I want essentially is this:

[image]

Please help me out! I have been stuck at this problem for a good month.

Comment: "If I can somehow get this dynamic list of the images from the preview area into an array" See `thumbsArray = []`; i.e., try adding ` console.log(thumbsArray);` to `read()` function body , click "Choose Files" , observe `thumbsArray` being updated at `console`. "What I want essentially is this: [Individual image delete functionlity]" ? See `.remove_thumb` class and `$list.on('click', '.remove_thumb', function () {})` , which appear to remove individual images on click of `:before` pseudo-element ? Same pseudo element could be adjusted to "Delete" , beneath images  utilizing `css` ?

Comment: By placing console.log(thumbsArray);, I got a giant list of characters that I assume is the picture in it's code form. Is there a way to get the fake paths of all the images within the preview area?